# Exclude views from a table_suffix query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Twillio Segment to sync web_app_ui events into bigquery (serves as data lake).
In Bigquery data we have many tables with similar structure. Most fields are common, but some are different.
We have many such tables (~200), and many are added regularly.
Each table has a [view](https://segment.com/docs/connections/storage/catalog/bigquery/#views) with similar structure aimed at records deduplication and performance optimization.
So I have a table: `mytable`, and next to it `mytable_view`

I would like to query all these tables together using Table_Suffix wildcard functionality. However... since eache table has a view that matches the wildcard, I get the error message: `Views cannot be queried through prefix.`

I am looking for an idea for going around this [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations). And querying all tables in one query, while ignoring all views. or in other words, how to make this work?

```
Select a,b,c
from `my_dataset`.*
where _TABLE_SUFFIX not like "%_view'
```

Comment: Is putting the Views in a different dataset a non-starter? It seems to me that this would solve your problem at a stroke.

Comment: Thank you. unfortunately, moving the views to a different data set is not supported by the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, table wildcard won't work if it would match both views and tables.
Eventually I went for the solution of creating a view using dynamic SQL.
I use this code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
with 
tbls as 
(
Select table_name 
from `<myproject>.<mydataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
where table_name not like '%_view' )

SELECT 
" CREATE VIEW `<myproject>.<mydataset>.<myview>` AS "||
STRING_AGG(
"SELECT a FROM `<myproject>.<mydataset>."||table_name||"`",
" UNION ALL ")
From tbls);
```

(simplified version)

This is scheduled to run daily. It creates a view that does Union All of all relevant tables.
One can also pick relevant fields in similar manner from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Ouch. Well done on finding a solution, though. I guess if you are going to construct queries dynamically and run them on a schedule a good next step might be to look into [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) or [dataform](https://cloud.google.com/dataform). Either might be best used with an additional package to perform this specific task (haven't used Dataform myself, but it is GCP native).

Comment: Thank you! I ran into this same issue (need a single view for all events synced by Segment to Bigquery) and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

- The wildcard table functionality does not support views. If the wildcard table matches any view in the dataset, the query returns an error. This is true whether or not your query contains a WHERE clause on the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column to filter out the view.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations

So, the only option you have is to isolate the views on a different dataset or project given that any _TABLE_SUFFIX will not be evaluated if there is any view matched by the wildcard in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, moving the views to a different data set is not supported by the vendor.